# The same URI path for REST with different methods OR different URI paths?

Tags: web-services, rest, http

What is the better way of using HTTP methods for REST:

**First variant**:

Send different HTTP methods to the same URL:

```
URL : item/{id}   method : DELETE   ---- DELETE item<br>
URL : item/{id}   method : PUT   ---- PUT item<br>
URL : item/{id}   method : GET   ---- GET item<br>
```

**OR second**:

Have a different URL for each HTTP method, and send each verb to its corresponding URL:

```
URL : deleteitem/{id} OR item/delete/{id}   method: DELETE ---- DELETE item<br>
URL : putitem/{id} OR item/put/{id}         method: PUT ----    PUT item<br>
URL : getitem/{id} OR item/get/{id}         method: GET ----    GET item<br>
```

Answer (score 5):

The first variant, with the methods applied to the same URI, is the REST way of doing things. With REST, you do the following:

- Identify a set of *resources* that your web application manipulates: *items* in your case.
- Give each resource an identifier (a URI) that the application and its clients can use to indicate a particular resource: `item/{id}` in your case.
- Identify manipulations of the resources that clients can perform.
- Use an HTTP method (verb) applied to a URI (noun) to express those manipulations.
- Have clients perform those operations by sending HTTP requests to the server, using those HTTP methods and URIs.